# $1/k\geq \log(k+1)-\log(k), ~k>0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Is there a more obvious reason for that inequality besides:

$1= \lim_{k\to \infty} \log(1+\frac{1}{k})^{k}$ and $\log(1+\frac{1}{k})^{k}$ is increasing.

Answer (score 1):

You have that $$\log(k+1)-\log(k)=\log\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)=\log\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)$$ Now, you need to show that $$t\ge \log(1+t)$$ or equivalently $$e^t \ge 1+t \implies e^t-1-t\ge0$$ which can be seen graphically as well as analytically, since $$(e^t-1-t)'=e^t-1>0$$ for $t\ge0$ and $e^0-1=0$. This means that this function is always nonnegative in the domain $t\ge 0$ (as an increasing function, that is nonnegative for $t=0$).

**Intuitively**, the above inequality holds, since the logarithm shrinks a value $t$ (and even $t+1$) to a value less than $t$ itself.

Answer (score 1):

$\log x=\int_1^x\frac1tdt$, so we have
$$\log(k+1)-\log k=\int_k^{k+1}\frac1tdt\leq\int_k^{k+1}\frac1kdt=\frac1k.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Mean value theorem applied to $f(x) = \log x$ on the interval $[k,k+1]$.